# compare changes between branches in git

Tags: git, branch, diff

I have a master branch. Then, I modified some files but realized that I want to have these changes in a feature branch. I created a feature branch and went on with modifying files.
But now, I need a clean master branch. But before I want to make sure that its save to discard the uncommitted changes there. 
Therefore, I wanted to compare these changes with the changes made in the feature branch. As they are not committed on both sides, I don't know how to do it...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unmodified or uncommitted changes are not related to branches. Its the state of your working tree!

Precisely, there is nothing like uncommitted changes on master branch or feature branch! The changes start belonging to a branch only after you commit!

So, If you do git diff it will show you the changes you will be committing which are not there on master. (Assuming you made feature branch from where master is).

I would recommend you read this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/

Specially Chapter 2 and 3.

Hope this answer!

Comment: You are completly right. Thank you. The misleading idea was that I'm working on branches and therefore modifications belong to that branch.